# After resume sometimes show the Home Screen on Nativescript-Vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a problem with my application and his navigation.

My app have four screens but sometimes when tap the android home button in the second screen (or any other) and after resume the app, this show the home screen and not the last screen, any ideas to resolve this?

Update:
Sometimes after resume the app, this show the correct screen (the last showed) but I don't know how this happen (it's the same source code), I tested this in many versions of android simulator (4.4, 5.0, 7.0  y 8.0). Can this be a bug?

Screen Recording:
https://i.imgur.com/VhWFhWU.gifv

Code:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=wKkYCe&v=2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be easy if you are using single frame in your application. You could listen to resume event of activity and call `$navigateBack` with a reference to first item in the back stack.

```
       if (application.android) {

 application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityResumedEvent,
                () => {
                    const backStack = frame.topmost().backStack[0];
                    if (backStack) {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                            this.$navigateBack({}, backStack);
                        }, 0);
                    }
                }, this);
        }
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=wKkYCe&v=3)

Comment: Thanks,It's weird because sometimes works ok with the same code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing the point. What seems to be wired, is it breaking sometimes? That's what you meant?

Comment: Without your code, sometimes when the app resume show the correct screen but it's difficult to reproduce. If I will use your code when resume the correct screen, this code will change the screen?

Comment: Yes, I assume that's what you asked for. Your question reads that after resume always show home screen. The above code goes back to your first component when you resume to your app. If that is not what you are expecting, please update your question with more details.

Comment: Actually I thought you were asking for something like that, navigate to home screen when you resume. But looks like it was your issue and I'm not sure how that could happen. Neither it's not reproduced on my end with same Playground. The only possible reason I could think of is, either you have some cleaning app running that kills your application as soon it goes into background Or there is a setting your developer options to destroy activity, may be that's enabled.